# Gsutil wildcard search

Tags: linux, unix, sh, gsutil

I have to search 2 files from list of files.

The 2 Files which I have to search are in format googlea_1234_20151208.txt and googleb_7654_20151208.txt, so i am thinking of basing my search on keyword googlea , googleb and 20151208 .

Using gsutil, i can find individual files.

Using command `gsutil ls gs://bucketid/*googlea_1234_20151208*` which gives me first file and  `gsutil ls gs://bucketid/*googlea_1234_20151208*` gives me 2nd file.

Looking for a command which will give me both files with one command 
    gsutil ls gs://bucketid/*google*20151208*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `gsutil` is just passing the `ls` args to a real `ls` type processor, try

```
 gsutil ls gs://bucketid/*google[ab]_*20151208*
```

The `[ab]` is know as a character-class. Rather than use `?` to match any single character, `[ab]` says, match a single char if it is `a` or `b`

IHTH

Comment: Can we parametrize the search pattern to some variable also?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand. Do you mean. but ` var='*[ab]*'; ls $var` works as I would expect. Of course the shell spports input params, like `$1`, and you can even do `var="$1"`. Good luck.